# Open file in .bundle using fopen()

Tags: ios, frameworks, bundle, fopen, resourcebundle

I have built a custom framework and accompanying resource bundle to be used in other projects. The resource bundle includes various .sqlite and .bin files. I am trying to open a .bin file in another project using my framework with no success.

Let's say my bundle is called **CustomFramework.bundle**. I have a class **ResourceHelper.cpp** within my framework that is attempting to open **mybin.bin** that is located in the **CustomFramework.bundle**.

Here is how I am currently trying to open it:

```
void ResourceHelper::openBinFromResourceFolder(FILE **file) {
    std::string path;
    path = "CustomFramework.bundle/";
    path.append("mybin.bin");
    *file = fopen(path.c_str(), "rb");
}
```

`file` is **NULL** after this fopen() call.

**How am i suppose to open a .bin file within my .bundle?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you have to get the main bundle string and append the resource bundle to that string. Here is how I got it working.

```
void ResourceHelper::openBinFromResourceFolder(const char *binName, FILE **file) {
    std::string path;
    // split bin name into name and file type (bin)
    std::string binStr = binName;
    std::size_t pos = binStr.find(".");
    std::string filename = binStr.substr(0, pos);
    std::string type = binStr.substr(pos+1);

    // get bundle and CFStrings
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFStringRef cf_resource_path = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, resourcePath_.c_str(), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    CFStringRef cf_filename = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, filename.c_str(), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    CFStringRef cf_file_type = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, type.c_str(), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    CFURLRef url_resource = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, cf_filename, cf_file_type, cf_resource_path);
    CFStringRef urlString = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath(url_resource, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle);
    path = CFStringGetCStringPtr(urlString, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    *file = fopen(path.c_str(), "rb");
}
```